# "The Guest House provide rooms" or "The Guest House provides rooms"?

Tags: plural-forms, singular

So what is the correct version? As I remember it should be "provides rooms", but "provide rooms" sounds more English.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This must be said with *provide**s***.

A verb agrees in person and number (singular, plural) with its subject. The subject here is *The Guest House* (not *I* or *we* or *you*, so 3rd person) and there is only one, so it requires the 3rd person **singular** form with *-s*.

Comment: Ok, thanks. You see -- I remembered the correct version.

Comment: @Adobe I suspect the plural form "sounds more English" because you have encountered the (mostly British) practice of using the plural with some singular nouns that comprise many individual members - sports teams, for instance. This confounds many foreigners, including Americans like me.

Comment: The thing I hate about English tests and the likes -- is that people actually use it in all ways. Then again, I seems to make a mistake in my question: it should be "sounds more English", because it is about "it", and "it" uses `verb + s/es`.

Comment: @Adobe Yes, indeed; but there is a core of uses which everybody observes, and a (mostly) fixed Standard English which will get you through the exams. (And, yes, "sound" is a mistake; but you may remedy it by editing your question.)

Comment: What @StoneyB said (in the comment, not the answer). In which context I'll just flag up that [The The are a British band](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22the+the+are+a+british+band%22&oq=%22the+the+are+a+british+band%22&aqs=chrome.0.57.11829j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8), and (in the circumstances! :) that statement seems like perfectly normal English to me.

Answer (score 1):

Per StoneyB's answer:

> The Guest House provides rooms.

is the correct usage. You can use **provide** with the [future simple tense](http://www.englishclub.com/grammar/verb-tenses_future.htm):

> The Guest House will provide rooms.

but, the following is incorrect, since The Guest House is a single object:

> <strike>The Guest House provide rooms.</strike>